# Bootstrap tags input - highlighting the selected option when using keyboard navigation

Tags: bootstrap-4, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I am updating a product that utilizes [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) with typeahead to work better with keyboard input.

One of the issues, which you can see if you look at the [tags input typeahead or later examples](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), is that when you try to select a tag with the up/down arrows on the keyboard, it doesn't highlight the option you have selected like the [Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) ones do, it just shows it in the main input area.

I am trying to figure out how I can make the selected option highlight, but I'm not sure where to start. The project hasn't been updated for four years, but has over a thousand forks, so maybe one of them has this feature, but I don't know how to go about finding out if that's true (and google hasn't helped).